# joining a pivot with another complex table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

my pivot query generates:

```
+-----------+----+----+---+---+---+---+---+
| client_id | 1  | 2  | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
+-----------+----+----+---+---+---+---+---+
|    216436 |  9 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|    110522 | 76 |  3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|    214981 |  0 |  1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|    216360 | 52 |  1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|    102574 |  1 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|    211754 | 97 | 14 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|    210734 |  8 |  4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|    100123 |  1 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|    101840 |  2 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+-----------+----+----+---+---+---+---+---+
```

here's the query:

```
   select client_id,
   [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7] -- these are timestested (the amount of times tested)
   from
   (   SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_ID
   , PATIENT_ID
   , count(*) over (partition by client_id, patient_id) AS patientcount

   from f_accession_daily) as SourceTable
   PIVOT
   (
   count(patient_id)
   for patientcount in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
   ) as pivottable
```

**I need to bring the max/min dates for every time tested, (for [1], [2], [3], etc)** from this table:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+------------+------------+
| client_id | TimesTested | count | maxRecDate | minRecDate |
+-----------+-------------+-------+------------+------------+
|    100034 |           2 |     1 | 6/25/2008  | 6/23/2008  |
|    100034 |           1 |    20 | 6/30/2008  | 6/19/2008  |
|    100038 |           3 |     1 | 7/25/2008  | 7/23/2008  |
|    100038 |           1 |     4 | 7/25/2008  | 7/1/2008   |
|    100050 |           1 |    15 | 8/11/2008  | 7/14/2008  |
|    100060 |           1 |     2 | 8/12/2008  | 7/29/2008  |
|    100070 |           1 |     3 | 8/15/2008  | 8/15/2008  |
|    100049 |           1 |     3 | 8/22/2008  | 7/11/2008  |
|    100029 |           3 |     2 | 8/25/2008  | 6/18/2008  |
+-----------+-------------+-------+------------+------------+
```

the above table is generated by:

```
SELECT a.client_id AS client_id
,a.patientcount TimesTested
   , count(a.patientcount)/a.patientcount AS count
   , max(f.received_date) AS maxRecDate
   , min(f.received_date) AS minRecDate
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_ID
   , PATIENT_ID
   , count(*) over (partition by client_id, patient_id) AS patientcount

   from f_accession_daily

) AS a
JOIN F_ACCESSION_DAILY AS f ON a.CLIENT_ID = f.CLIENT_ID
   AND a.PATIENT_ID = f.PATIENT_ID

GROUP BY a.CLIENT_ID, a.patientcount
```

**the resulting table that i need to get:**

```
+-----------+----+----------+-----------+----+----------+-----------+---+----------+-----------+---+----------+-----------+-----+
| client_id | 1  | maxdate1 | mindate1  | 2  | maxdate2 | mindate2  | 3 | maxdate3 | mindate3  | 4 | maxdate4 | mindate4  |  5  |
+-----------+----+----------+-----------+----+----------+-----------+---+----------+-----------+---+----------+-----------+-----+
|    216436 |  9 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 |  0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 | 0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 | 0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 | etc |
|    110522 | 76 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1984 |  3 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1984 | 0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1984 | 0 | 2/1/2011 | 1/23/1984 |     |
|    214981 |  0 | 1/1/2013 | 1/23/1985 |  1 | 1/1/2013 | 1/23/1985 | 0 | 1/1/2013 | 1/23/1985 | 0 | 1/1/2013 | 1/23/1985 |     |
|    216360 | 52 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 |  1 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 | 0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 | 0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 |     |
|    102574 |  1 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 |  0 | 1/1/2014 | 1/23/1980 | 0 | 2/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 | 0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 |     |
|    211754 | 97 | 1/1/2012 | 1/23/1985 | 14 | 1/1/2012 | 1/23/1985 | 2 | 1/1/2012 | 1/23/1985 | 0 | 1/1/2012 | 1/23/1985 |     |
|    210734 |  8 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1984 |  4 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1984 | 0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1984 | 0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1984 |     |
|    100123 |  1 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 |  0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 | 0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 | 0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1987 |     |
|    101840 |  2 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 |  0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1980 | 0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 | 0 | 1/1/2011 | 1/23/1985 |     |
+-----------+----+----------+-----------+----+----------+-----------+---+----------+-----------+---+----------+-----------+-----+
```

**how do i join the two tables? the speed does not matter! thank you very much for your kind help.**

Comment: so looks like it has to join both on client_id AND the 1, 2, 3, 4..(which is TimesTested )

Comment: where is @JNK when you need him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest, but I left your original queries intact and put it all in one [big] statement:

```
;WITH 
PivotQuery as (
    select client_id,
       [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]
       from
       (   SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_ID
       , PATIENT_ID
       , count(*) over (partition by client_id, patient_id) AS patientcount

       from f_accession_daily) as SourceTable
       PIVOT
       (
       count(patient_id)
       for patientcount in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
       ) as pivottable),

MinMaxTimes as (
    SELECT a.client_id AS client_id
    ,a.patientcount TimesTested
       , count(a.patientcount)/a.patientcount AS count
       , max(f.received_date) AS maxRecDate
       , min(f.received_date) AS minRecDate
    FROM
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_ID
       , PATIENT_ID
       , count(*) over (partition by client_id, patient_id) AS patientcount

       from f_accession_daily

    ) AS a
    JOIN F_ACCESSION_DAILY AS f ON a.CLIENT_ID = f.CLIENT_ID
       AND a.PATIENT_ID = f.PATIENT_ID

    GROUP BY a.CLIENT_ID, a.patientcount),

maxDates as (
SELECT client_id, [1] maxdate1, [2] maxdate2, [3] maxdate3, [4] maxdate4, [5] maxdate5, [6] maxdate6, [7] maxdate7
FROM MinMaxTimes t
PIVOT (max(maxRecDate)
for TimesTested IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
) as p),

minDates as (
SELECT client_id, [1] mindate1, [2] mindate2, [3] mindate3, [4] mindate4, [5] mindate5, [6] mindate6, [7] mindate7
FROM MinMaxTimes t
PIVOT (max(minRecDate)
for TimesTested IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
) as p)

SELECT p.client_id, 
    p.[1], max(maxdate1) maxdate1, max(mindate1) mindate1,
    p.[2], max(maxdate2) maxdate2, max(mindate2) mindate2,
    p.[3], max(maxdate3) maxdate3, max(mindate3) mindate3,
    p.[4], max(maxdate4) maxdate4, max(mindate4) mindate4,
    p.[5], max(maxdate5) maxdate5, max(mindate5) mindate5,
    p.[6], max(maxdate6) maxdate6, max(mindate6) mindate6,
    p.[7], max(maxdate7) maxdate7, max(mindate7) mindate7   
FROM PivotQuery p
LEFT OUTER JOIN maxDates a ON p.client_id = a.client_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN mindates i ON a.client_id = i.client_id
GROUP BY p.client_id, p.[1], p.[2], p.[3], p.[4], p.[5], p.[6], p.[7]
```

Comment: WOW! this looks prety amazing!! don't you want to throw in some conditions where maxdate1 is not null and mindate1 is not null and max date2 is not null etc... and do LEFT join instead of inner join?

Comment: Yeah, a left join should cover those being null, I'll add that.

Comment: i think the nulls will still be there like this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic595948-1063-1.aspx

Comment: That is a good point; I added groupings to try to get rid of that problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to join the two queries. Moreover, there's no need to use a self join either. Here's how you could go about selecting all the necessary data in one query:

```
WITH counted AS (
  SELECT
    client_id,
    COUNT(*) AS TimesTested,
    MAX(received_date) AS maxdate,
    MIN(received_date) AS mindate
  FROM f_accession_daily
  GROUP BY
    client_id,
    patient_id
),
counted2 AS (
  SELECT
    client_id,
    TimesTested,
    CAST(COUNT(*) AS varchar(30)) AS count,
    CAST(MAX(maxdate) AS varchar(30)) AS maxdate,
    CAST(MIN(mindate) AS varchar(30)) AS mindate
  FROM counted
  GROUP BY
    client_id,
    TimesTested
),
unpivoted AS (
  SELECT
    client_id,
    ColumnName + CAST(TimesTested AS varchar(10)) AS ColumnName,
    ColumnValue
  FROM counted2
  UNPIVOT (
    ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN (count, maxdate, mindate)
  ) u
),
pivoted AS (
  SELECT
    client_id,
    count1, maxdate1, mindate1,
    count2, maxdate2, mindate2,
    count3, maxdate3, mindate3,
    count4, maxdate4, mindate4,
    count5, maxdate5, mindate5,
    count6, maxdate6, mindate6,
    count7, maxdate7, mindate7
  FROM unpivoted
  PIVOT (
    MAX(ColumnValue) FOR ColumnName IN (
      count1, maxdate1, mindate1,
      count2, maxdate2, mindate2,
      count3, maxdate3, mindate3,
      count4, maxdate4, mindate4,
      count5, maxdate5, mindate5,
      count6, maxdate6, mindate6,
      count7, maxdate7, mindate7
    )
  ) p
)
SELECT *
FROM pivoted
;
```

Here's how this works:

1. The first CTE (`counted`) groups data by `client_id` and `patient_id` and calculates the row count, the maximum date and the minimum date for every group.
2. The second CTE (`counted2`) groups the previous result set by `client_id` and column containing the row count (called `TimesTested`) and again counts the rows and finds the max and min dates per group. The rowset produced is similar to the second table in your question, except `count` is just `COUNT(*)` (because that's what your first query calculates). Additionally, all the aggregated results are converted into strings, to prepare them for unpivoting.
3. The following CTE, `unpivoted`, does the above-mentioned unpivoting, producing a rowset like this:

   ```
   client_id  ColumnName  ColumnValue
   ---------  ----------  -----------
   211754     count1      97
   211754     maxdate1    1/1/2012
   211754     mindate1    1/23/1985
   211754     count1      14
   211754     maxdate1    1/1/2012
   211754     mindate1    1/23/1985
   ...
   ```
4. The final CTE, `pivoted`, performs the final step, pivoting of the result of the previous CTE, ultimately producing the output you want.

Comment: are you sure by the way that it should be count(*) in count2? shouldnt you be summing and getting averages of the testfrequencies?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: The OP's first query shows just COUNTs (calculated as `count(patient_id)` in the PIVOT clause), and their request was to add the dates from the second query. So I'm calculating the `count1`, `count2` etc. values as in the first query and the dates as in the second query.

Comment: i was wondering if you can help with this one please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034169/how-to-aggregate-values-from-a-pivot